How to "wake-up" user space threads from kernel?
Suppose you have a kernel device driver receiving data and a user space threads waiting for the data.
You want to avoid wasted cycles by having the user space thread block and wake-up once the kernel driver has processed the data and put it in an appropriate buffer.
What is the appropriate way to do this? I have read mixed thoughts on using signals.

You could write to a file in sysfs and have that signal your userspace thread to wake up (i.e., Userspace thread uses /sys file content as a signal, e.g., 1 = go, 0 =  wait).

Have you considered the asynchronous I/O system calls (e.g., https://linux.die.net/man/3/aio_read )?
